# Connecting selenium driver to CEF desktop application

Tags: python, selenium, chromium-embedded

I want to use Selenium WebDriver to run automated tests in a CEF window that is embedded in an application. When i run application with debug console enabled, and then i start my test i'm getting following error:

> SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created from unknown error: unhandled inspector error: ("code":-32601, "message":"'Target.setAutoAtach' wasn't found")

How can I fix this error? Or there is another way to connect to CEF desktop application?

My C# code:

```
Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings
{
    RemoteDebuggingPort = 55555,
    Locale = ResourcesController.GetResource("Locale"),
    LogSeverity = LogSeverity.Disable
});
ChromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(mainHtml)
{
    Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
    BrowserSettings = new BrowserSettings
    {
        FileAccessFromFileUrls = CefState.Enabled,
        UniversalAccessFromFileUrls = CefState.Enabled,
    },
    MenuHandler = new CustomContextMenuHandler()
};
```

And automation test in python:

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import os

CEF_PORT = "55555"
DEBUGGER_ADDRESS = "localhost:{}".format(CEF_PORT)
CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = "C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe"
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + r'C:\chromedriver'

class LoginTest(unittest.TestCase):
    window_handle_main = None

    def setUp(cls):
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.debugger_address = DEBUGGER_ADDRESS

    def test_button_login_click(self):
        WebDriverWait(self.instance, 5).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "btnLogin")))
        self.instance.find_element_by_id("btnLogin").click()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.instance.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

I'm using latest version of chromedriver (2.43).

Comment: The official `CEF` guide is https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/UsingChromeDriver.md
Last I checked you couldn't attach `Selenium` to an already running instance, has this changed?

Comment: No and i'm out of ideas. Now i'm trying to start application from selenium test code like in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xfyDIz7Mk0U. I'll edit main post if i have any updates.